Subscribing to the same topic from two nodes causes doubled network load
I am using ROS2 with default fast dds. When subscribing to the same topic from multiple nodes(subscribers are on the same device, publisher on different device) I see that the same rtps message is repeated for each subscriber.
How can I make different subscribers use same message to decrease network load?
